# Framework for handling transactions/wallets in multiple altcoins generically

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-development

I'm wondering the framework Poloniex, C-CEX and other bigger exchanges use to handle accounts and transactions for such a high number of cryptocurrencies.

What could I use to generically be able to handle accounts and transactions in as many altcoins as possible?